# How to get all google fit activities performed for a day

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I know how to get various data from google Fit like steps or calories when I specifically subscribe to them. 
However how can I retrieve all activities that user performed without knowing which ones they did exactly?

Also how can I get values for activities such as Stairs climbing?
It isn't available in DataType class, the samples on google developer website only show steps and calories.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I can only find all exercises using the Sessions API.

Crete a request first.

The:

```
.read(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE)
```

is important here to get all workouts.

```
    private SessionReadRequest readFitnessSession() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Build a session read request
    SessionReadRequest readRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE)
            .readSessionsFromAllApps()
            .build();
    // [END build_read_session_request]

    return readRequest;
}
```

And read the sessions data

```
    private void readSessionsApiAllSessions() {

    SessionReadRequest readRequest = readFitnessSession();

    Fitness.getSessionsClient(getActivity(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()))
            .readSession(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SessionReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SessionReadResponse sessionReadResponse) {
                    // Get a list of the sessions that match the criteria to check the result.
                    List<Session> sessions = sessionReadResponse.getSessions();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Session read was successful. Number of returned sessions is: "
                            + sessions.size());

                    for (Session session : sessions) {
                        // Process the session
                        dumpSession(session);

                        // Process the data sets for this session
                        List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResponse.getDataSet(session);
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                            dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to read session");
                }
            });

}
```